# how can i merge rows with timestamp and limited by id and looping it?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

how can i merge rows with timestamp and limited by id, and looping it then makes a second table which is the result data of merging rows (on first table) ?

```
id     | data     | time      
---------------------------------------
100    | 4        | 2012-02-01 08:00:00 
99     | 3        | 2012-02-01 07:59:00 
98     | 2        | 2012-02-01 07:58:00 
97     | 3        | 2012-02-01 07:57:00 
.
.
2      | 3        | 2012-01-31 11:02:00
1      | 2        | 2012-01-31 11:01:00
100    | 4        | 2012-01-31 11:00:00 
99     | 3        | 2012-01-31 10:59:00 
98     | 3        | 2012-01-31 10:58:00 
97     | 3        | 2012-01-31 10:57:00 
.
.
.
etc.
```

if i wanna merge rows from id = 100 to 1, and merge another rows again from id = 100 to 1 with timestamp information, make a new table that should be like this :

```
id     | data          | time
---------------------------------------
1      | 4,3,2,3,..3,2 | 2012-02-01 08:00:00 
2      | 4,3,3,3,..    | 2012-01-31 11:00:00
.
.
etc.
```

which is field 'data' is collecting data from field 'data' on first table
and field 'time' is information time for every limitation to id = 100 from field 'time' on first table

Comment: What does the `id` column contain in the second table? Looks like it is not necessary

Comment: id column in the second table is primary key, it will increasing by adding new record.

Comment: Ok. Adding to the table is a trivial task and the ID is automatically generated so there is no need to provide that in the results of the query

Comment: its your command codes thats can be applied in phpmyadmin ? im using mysql for database and phymyadmin for php's database application

Comment: when i'm running this code on sql (with phpmyadmin) its loading too long, it is because i have too many data in rows for merging to one row? 'time' in your sql code initializing field 't' or a variable? can you explain me flow chart of the sql code you are wrote?

Answer (score 0):

It was a bit harder than I thought but here it is:

```
SELECT group_concat(data ORDER BY time DESC) data, max(id) aTime
FROM (
  SELECT CASE WHEN id = 100 THEN time END id, data, time,
    @group := @group + (id = 100) aGroup
  FROM t, (SELECT @group := 0) init
  ORDER BY time DESC
) s
GROUP BY aGroup
```

Output:

```
|        DATA |                      ATIME |
|-------------|----------------------------|
| 4,3,2,3,3,2 | February, 01 2012 08:00:00 |
|     4,3,3,3 |  January, 31 2012 11:00:00 |
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/577508/1).

Note the `id` column in your results is not clear where it comes from and it also seems to be unnecessary.

Comment: when i'm running this code on sql (with phpmyadmin) its loading too long, it is because i have too many data in rows for merging to one row? 'time' in your sql code initializing field 't' or a variable? can you explain me flow chart of the sql code you are wrote?

Comment: The main reason for this to take long is that there is a derived table with an order by. However, there is no other way to go in MySQL. Your best approach could be using a `select * .. order by time` and then process the results in a lower level language (eg: php)